# Error report from Google Play, Database import error

Tags: android, database, runtime-error

If I understand correctly something is wrong on the splash, something with importing database. What could it be? It works fine on some of the devices. I tried to delete importing database at the splash but then no data from database is shown later in app.

I got this error on my google play error report:

```
    java.lang.Error: Error copying database
at com.ribicinc.ugani.DataBaseHelper.createDataBase(DataBaseHelper.java:61)
at com.ribicinc.ugani.Splash.importdb(Splash.java:66)
at com.ribicinc.ugani.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:27)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is also my splash code:

```
package com.ribicinc.ugani;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.graphics.LightingColorFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import java.io.IOException;


public class Splash extends Activity {
    private final int DURATION = 3000;
    private Thread mSplashThread;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        importdb();

        ProgressBar pBar2 = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress);
        pBar2.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0x80deea, 0x80deea));


        mSplashThread = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized (this) {
                    try {
                        wait(DURATION);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    } finally {
                        finish();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                                Main.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                      }
                }
            }

        };
        mSplashThread.start();


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_splash, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void importdb(){
        //import database*
        try {
            DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
            myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
            try {
                myDbHelper.createDataBase();

            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                throw new Error("Napaka!");
            }
            try {
                myDbHelper.openDataBase();
            }catch(SQLException sqle){
                throw sqle;
            }
        }catch(SQLException sqle){

        }

        //import database*
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you have a double  `new DataBaseHelper(this);`?

Comment: Oh, haven't noticed it. Could this be the problem?

Comment: I doubt. Can you post the DataBaseHelper?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/JCB7xrbh

Comment: what if `DB_PATH` doesn't exist?

Comment: It does, because on the other activity works perfectly.

Comment: what does *on the other activity* mean?

Comment: In another activity in this app I use database, and it works.

Comment: isn't the splash the first activity ?

Comment: Yes it is. But as I said, app works fine on some of the devices, but from one tablet this is the error I got.